# Как сделать ссылку кликабельной в блоке со скруглами

Tags: css

В сети нашел интересное решение для скруглов. Все хорошо, но если в блок вставить ссылку, но она не кликабельна. В чем проблема и как решить?

https://jsbin.com/yenodeb/edit?html,css,output

```css
.corners {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 240px;
  width: 310px;
}
.text {
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #9b9b9b;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.arc-top,
.arc-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.arc-top:before,
.arc-top:after,
.arc-bottom:before,
.arc-bottom:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #9b9b9b;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.arc-top:before {
  top: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}
.arc-top:after {
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
}
.arc-bottom:before {
  bottom: -12px;
  left: -12px;
}
.arc-bottom:after {
  bottom: -12px;
  right: -12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="corners">
    <div class="arc-top"></div>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Zagolovok</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <a title="" href="#">Aenean commodo</a> ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="arc-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: вы же видите что там обманка ?

Comment: Там дивы на 100% высоты... сделайте их высотой например `25px`. При этом еще у верхнего сделайте параметр `top:0`, а у нижнего `bottom:0`, вместо top ......а отсюда `.arc-top, .arc-bottom {`  скорее надо будет убрать `top:0`

Comment: .text - position:relative;  z-index: 1;

Comment: Обманка в чем? Классы arc-top и arc-bottom перекрывают текст из-за абсолютного позиционирования. Такой слой не дает кликнуть по ссылке. А решение? ))

Comment: Если добавить .text - position:relative; z-index: 1; то теряются скруглы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, нарушаются все скруглы.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7qb7kjew/

Comment: @Apsolyamov ничего не нарушается. Надо просто основы css знать. 25px я для примера взял, надо было 12, а вы наверно слепо 25 поставили и всё, ничего не работает караул))...........https://jsbin.com/hiloxakoqu/1/edit?html,css,output  вот сделано как я сказал. Что нарушилось?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, увидел решение. Спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Убери:

```
.arc-top,
.arc-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[Рабочий пример](http://codepen.io/mrtoxas/pen/JXQQzL)